# c# pointers to variables

Tags: c#, design-patterns, pointers

C# question.

I have an inheritance hierarchy that looks like this:

```
BaseController
    Object1Controller
    Object2Controller
    Object3Controller
        Object3_1Controller
```

Instances of objects 1 2 and 3 calculate a value using a value in the base controller, but object 3_1 does not.

These objects can have other objects attached to them that modify base values for a time and then revert them to a cached value. (Ignoring the horrifying implications of this OO nightmare :P )

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
class modifier<T>
T* pointerToValue
void assignModifiable(T*)
```

Such that every modifiable class creates a modifier and has it point to the variable it wants to be modified. The c++ equivalent would be something like this:

```
template <class T> class ModifierInterface
{
    T* modifiableVariable;
    void setModifier( T &target )
    { modifiableVariable = target }

    void changeModifiable( T val )
    { modifiableVariable = val }
}
```

Comment: you can just use `ref`.

Comment: Not with pointers anyway. You'd have to pin almost everything and you would choke the Garbage collector.

Comment: pointers are rarely needed for c#.

Comment: Usually, rather than bind to a member *variable*, code binds to a member *property* because you can get delegates (function pointers) to its getter and setters. These delegates can be closed (tied to an object) or open (accepting an object as first parameter).

Comment: Daniel:
What you are suggesting is:
    
    `T* pointerToValue; SetVal( ref T variable )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here seems to be a wrapper class for your values:

```
class Modifiable<T>
{
    public T Value { get; st; }
    ...
}

class Object1Controller : ...
{
    public Modifiable<int> MyValue { get; private set; }
}
```

This is not complete but it is what I can make of your question.  A `Modifiable<int>` would have most properties of an `int*`.

Comment: No, that is only allowed on parameters anyway and you could do this without (many) methods.

Comment: also, I am sorry that my question is confusing. I am trying to think of a more complete way of wording it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: quick question. Does this definitely insure that the value is changed at source? I didn't think c# passed by reference. 
I.e.

objectController1 sets its modifiable to point at myVar in base.
When I change modifiable, myVar changes??

Comment: Classes (as opposed to structs) are passed by reference. `Modifiable<T>` is a class.

Comment: Read up about Value-types and Reference-types and you will understand why we don't really need pointers in C#